# Extract sections from text file separated by specific characters in bash

Tags: string, bash, shell

I have some simple text files in bash that look something like this

```
>Position 1
ABCD
EFGH
IJKL
MNOP
QRST
UVWX
YZ
>Position 2
abcd
efgh
ijkl
mnop
qrst
uvwx
yz
>Position 3
...
```

(Alphabet and capitalization only used as example)

What I want is to be able to extract each of these sections (A-Z) between "headers" (>Position) and break them into strings of length n to send to a file. For example, if n=10 my output should be

```
ABCDEFGHIJ
KLMNOPQRST
UVWXYZ
abcdefghij
klmnopqrst
uvwxyz
```

I need to do this on a very large file with close to a million lines, so efficiency is key.

My current method isn't very efficient and goes as follows:

```
cat file.txt | while read line; do
    if [[ "$line" != '>'* ]]; then
        section="$section$line"
    else
        echo $section | fold -w 10 >> fragments.txt
        section=''
    fi
done
```

In summary it builds each "section" until it reaches a new '>' header, at which point it spits out the fragmented content.

I want something that can give the same result much more efficiently if possible. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another awk:

```
$ awk -v n=10 '
BEGIN {
    if(!n)                       # test that there an n
        exit 1                   # or exit 
}
{
    if(/^>Position/)             # >Position outputs buffer b
        while(b!="") {           # while buffer left
            print substr(b,1,n)  # output in pieces
            b=substr(b,n+1)      # shorten buffer (counter probly faster)
        }
    else                         # no >Position
        b=b $0                   # buffer to b
}' file
```

Output with given data and `n=10`:

```
ABCDEFGHIJ
KLMNOPQRST
UVWXYZ
abcdefghij
klmnopqrst
uvwxyz
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do using pure [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) solution:

```
awk -v n=10 '$1 ~ /^>Position/{++count;next} count==n+1{exit} 1' file
```

Same multi lines:

```
awk -v n=10 '
    $1 ~ /^>Position/{++count;next} # if first column match 'Position', pre-increment count
    count==n+1{exit}                # if count == n, exit
    1                               # print current line
' file
```